# type variable in datatype definition

Tags: coq, isabelle, formal-languages, formal-verification

I want to modify the datatype which is now defined as below.

```
datatype assn = 
    Aemp                                           (*r Empty heap *)
  | Apointsto exp exp    (infixl "⟼" 200)        (*r Singleton heap *)
  | Astar assn assn      (infixl "**" 100)         (*r Separating conjunction *)
  | Awand assn assn                                (*r Separating implication *)
  | Apure bexp                                     (*r Pure assertion *)
  | Aconj assn assn                                (*r Conjunction *)
  | Adisj assn assn                                (*r Disjunction *)
  | Aex "(nat ⇒ assn)"                            (*r Existential quantification *)
```

I want to modify the last line to allow a more flexible existence definition, something like`Aex "('a ⇒ assn)"`, however, the ide notice me with the error message `Extra type variables on right-hand side: "'a"` .  By the way,  I can write   `Aex (A: Type) (pp: A -> assn).` in Coq. Therefore, I wonder wether I can do it in Isabelle and how?

Comment: This question was asked in multiple places. I answered it https://isabelle.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/211483-Isabelle.2FML/topic/type.20variable.20in.20datatype.20definition/near/312769702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of putting the answer here too: In Isabelle you have to specify what the dependencies of the types. Therefore, you need to write:

```
datatype 'a assn =
  ...
```

And if you had several ones, you would write:

```
datatype ('a, 'b, 'c, 'd) assn =
  ...
```

Remark that the error message "Extra XXX on the right-hand side" means there is something on the right-hand side that is missing from the left-hand side of the equality. Depending on the context, this could be some extra variable, some extra type (like here), or anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A question for this implementation is that different assertions cannot be operated. For instance, 'a assn cannot conjucture or star with 'b assn. Any advice for that?

Comment: Either you need an invariant that captures that. Or different datatypes.